# Leaflet map showing blank space while collapsing left panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I'm designing a portal of leaflet. I need to change leaflet div width while collapsing left panel. So by default I have put width of div this

```
 .map-wrapper {
        width: Calc(100vw - 33vw);
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

When I collapse my left panel then I'm adding a class in .map-wrapper

```
.shrink-map {
    width: Calc(100vw - 5vw) !important;
    transition: .6s linear;
}
```

It's perfectly collapsed but map is not loading proper. It's showing blank space in right side[image]. how to solve this. Kindly check image001 and image 002 for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to refresh the map while or after „flying out“ the panel so it calculates the available space for the map and draws it in full width and height of the container. See the [API docs for the `invalidatesize` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize).

> Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so — call it after you've changed the map size dynamically, also animating pan by default.

PS: It would be really helpful to have a „live“ demo of this behaviour.